# Finding a specific hash in a large amount of files (within .rar bundle)

Tags: windows, linux, scripting, antivirus, hard-drive

Are there any programs out there that will scour a hard drive for a specific MD5 hash? I'm specifically looking for hashes that may be located within .zip or .rar files.

I've tried writing Python scripts for this, but it's having problems with some of the non-English file names.

So... does something like this already exist? Hopefully free and open-source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand: you want to find a file of a particular given MD5 sum, or you want to find MD5 strings (that is 32 hex digits) on your disk?

If you want to find a file of a given MD5 sum (let's pretend it is `01234a4d035addca808644a0163abcdef` here), I would try to run (but it will take time) something to compute the MD5 of every file with e.g.

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; > /tmp/allmd5sum.txt
```

and then seek (with `fgrep 01234a4d035addca808644a0163abcdef /tmp/allmd5sum.txt` for instance) the particular given MD5 sum inside.

Of course, be careful when running *find* (so read its documentation), in particular to avoid file trees like `/proc` or even `/tmp`

Comment: This seems really close! Except I need the md5sums of all the files in ALL of my .rar and .zip files recursively (because there could be more folders or compressed files in there). Any idea how we can modify the command to do that?

Comment: You might unzip or unrar the file in a temporary directory and recurse the script inside it.

Comment: I have hundreds, if not thousands, of .rar and .zip files to go through though...

Comment: So what? First experiment your scripts on a subset of them. And what you are asking for is intensive processing, so it will take some time. Your script could remove the temporary directory in which it extracted the .zip or .rar file after completion.

Comment: Okay, so this is basically what I came up with from what you gave me. I'm using sed to so I can create the temp directories to extract to while retaining the basic filestructure so I know where each file is physically located.

<code><pre>for foo in `find . -name "*.rar"`; do export temp=/tmp/`echo $foo | sed 's:\.:^:g' | sed 's:/:=:g'` && mkdir $temp && unrar x $foo $temp && find $temp -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; >> /tmp/allmd5sum.txt && rm -rf $temp; done;</pre></code>